# How to know when user logged in with gmail has received an email NODEJS

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I am developing a web app which consists in parsing users emails and then applying some templates and other stuff.

After the user has logged in with his gmail and give me permissions to read the email, the app can read and parse emails just fine, the only problem is that I do not know when he recieved a new email.

People have suggested me to make a function that from time to time checks if theres a new email but my goal is to avoid that as much as possible.
Also, i've checked nodejs email listener but it requires user email and password which I do not have (I only have the token with the permissions to make requests in gmail api nothing more).

So to put it simply, how can the server know when user has recieved an email in his gmail inbox.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When User Login send A E-mail
by using Nodemailer
for More Info https://nodemailer.com/about/

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear enough but, from what I read about nodemail, it is for sending emails only. What i am looking for is just to notify the server that a new mail has reached the user gmail inbox